# iTunesConnect - why sales difference between "App Analytics" and "Sales and Trends"?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, ios

I'm tracking the progress of my new app, and each day it is exciting to see new numbers. However, today I noticed a big difference between what's reported via iTunesConnect and App Analytics

- iTunesConnect App Analytics - 447 units on April 18
- iTunesConnect
  Sales and Trends - 23700 units on April 18

Numbers for previous days match. Does it takes some time to update the app analytics? Such big difference is huge for morale :0